# Type of URL to choose for different activities

Tags: url

I'm doing 2 totally different activities under one name and I would like to create a website for both under one domain name. For example, the website will be `example.com`. How should I arrange it better:

1. `activity1.example.com` and `activity2.example.com`?

OR

2. `example.com/activity1` and `example.com/activity2`?

What do you think is better. I would choose the solution #1, but regarding the SEO and other practices which would be better?

Answer (score 0):

If your activities are really totally different, i would recommend to drive with subdomains. If there is a possibility, that your activities would profit from each other content and traffic - use subfolder.